# Need some help in appending more than one line to a file in puppet

Tags: linux, puppet, rhel

Using this manifest

```
file_line { 'sudo_rule':
   path => '/etc/sudoers',
   line => '%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL',
}
```

Puppet adds a line, but I want more than one line to append to a file.

Comment: Why not use a sudo module (e.g. [`puppetlabs-sudoers`](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-sudo) or [`camtocamp-sudo`](https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-sudo)) which will make it easier to manage sudoers?

Answer (score 0):

File_line only

> Ensures that a given line is contained within a file. ([according to the doc](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib/blob/master/lib/puppet/type/file_line.rb))

So you may add more lines to your puppet configuration file and it will work out of the box since puppet only ensures that they are there but doesn't add them continuously.

Maybe you tell us what your usecase is so that we can help you better. Another option would also be [augeas](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/puppet_augeas) to load config files into a tree like datastructure and edit the appropriate values in place.

Example usage:

```
augeas { "sshd_config":
  context => "/files/etc/ssh/sshd_config",
  changes => [
    "set PermitRootLogin no",
  ],
}
```

Comment: Your description of "File_line" is good, and explains why the OPs current approach isn't working, but I think this may be more appropriate as a comment. It doesn't really provide an *answer* to the question. In particular, requests for more information should definitely be in comments, not answers.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried to give a alternative answer as well, I'm currently not allowed to post comments that's why I instead asked for the information in the "answer" as well.